# how to create the transition with animations in the link

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create a transition animation like in the link below.. please help if anyone knows how to do this
 https://dribbble.com/shots/6488787-Music-App-UI-Pages

I tried to zoom image.. and i need this view in every view controller in the app so i tried to do it as a base view controller

I tried to add the bar in the right side of the screen. but now struggling to do the effect as the design shows

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    var buttonImage = UIImageView()
    var strechyImage = UIImageView()
    var boxviewImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpView()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch : UITouch! = touches?.first
        location = touch.location(in: self.view)

        strechyImage.center = location


    }

    func setUpView() {


        let viewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        //FloatButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Icon ionic-md-sad"), for: .normal)

        boxviewImage.image = UIImage(named: "nfc box")
        boxviewImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 200)
        let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        currentWindow?.addSubview(boxviewImage)
        //view.addSubview(boxviewImage)

        strechyImage.image = UIImage(named: "nfc curve")
        strechyImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
        view.addSubview(strechyImage)


        buttonImage.image = UIImage(named: "nfc floating")
        buttonImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
        strechyImage.addSubview(buttonImage)
        //view.bringSubviewToFront(buttonImage)

        buttonImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        strechyImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        boxviewImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            strechyImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 1),
            strechyImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.142),
            strechyImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3),

            strechyImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -(viewHeight / 20)),


            buttonImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.1),
            buttonImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.055),
            buttonImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: strechyImage.centerXAnchor, multiplier: -0.9),
            buttonImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: strechyImage.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 0),

            boxviewImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentWindow!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 2.2),
            boxviewImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: currentWindow!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.0255),
            boxviewImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight),

            ])


    }

}
```

Need to create this transition as close as possible to the design in the link

Comment: You could use [FloatingMenu](https://github.com/yannickl/FlowingMenu)

Comment: thank you.. i need to create this without any pods.

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions Awesome. That's a great learning oppurtunity for you. You need to implement `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. You can find lots of good tutorial on it. Good luck.

Comment: @VSoftwareSolutions, [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/elastic-view-animation-or-how-i-built-dgelasticpulltorefresh-269a3ba8636e#.9dioekqv6) is the logic that could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much ill look into it

Comment: Still having trouble.. nothing seems to work as it is.. can anyone help me with some code on this